# BigQuery Literal Column Names

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to find how to refer to columns made by creating literal SELECTs?

For example:
`SELECT ("BoB", "San Jose") as data` returns two unnamed columns

Now I want to use those column in a subsequent condition or operation

Usually I would do `data.column_name = othertable.column_name` in the conditional statements

How do I use these columns if they are unnamed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of below options (BigQuery Standard SQL):

```
SELECT STRUCT("BoB" AS col1 , "San Jose" AS col2) AS data
```

OR

```
SELECT STRUCT<col1 STRING, col2 STRING>("BoB", "San Jose") AS data
```

and then you can reference them as `data.col1` or `data.col2`